# Setting up and understanding a controller

Tags: modules, controller

I'm trying to set up a module with a controller as bit of a learning tool. The learning is not going well so far. Here is my setup:

```
- modules
- - site
- - - playing
- - - - Playing.php
- - - - controllers
- - - - - PlayingController.php
```

Inside `config/app.php` I have: `"playing" => site\playing\Playing::class` and it's being bootstraped.

```
# modules/site/playing/Playing.php

namespace site\playing;

use yii\base\Module;

class Playing extends Module
{

}
```

```
# modules/site/playing/controllers/PlayingController.php

namespace site\playing\controllers {

use craft\web\Controller;

class PlayingController extends Controller
  {
    public function actionTag() {
      echo 'This works';
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a route `'playing' => 'site/playing/tag'`, but when I go to `mysite.dev/playing` I get a 404.

I'm sure it's just something super simple I'm missing but I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your namespacing.

In `config/app.php`:

```php
'modules' => [
    'playing' => modules\site\Playing::class,
],
'bootstrap' => ['playing'],
```

In `modules/site/playing/controllers/PlayingController.php`

```php
namespace modules\site\controllers
```

In your `composer.json`

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "modules\\site\\": "modules/site/playing"
    }
},
```

Then `composer dump-autoload -a`.

After this, your `https://example.site/actions/playing/playing/tag` action should work without a route.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typical controller path - *actions*/*handle*/*controller*/*action*

So probably it should be:

```
'actions/playing/playing/tag => '/playing',
```

or

```
'actions'/playing/playing/tag => ['template' => 'playing'],
```

Also, did you tell the composer to add a new class?

```
composer dump-autoload -a
```

Comment: Hmm so my route works like this `'playing' => 'playing/playing/tag',` but I now get a 403 error and trying to workout why.

Comment: Adding `public int|bool|array $allowAnonymous = true;` makes it work but it's got no context of anything it seems; despite being logged in, `Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()` returns null...hence the 403 error I guess.